# using iphone or Android as GPS device

Tags: drone.io

I'm trying to make an autonomous drone and use the "follow_me" code from example of dronekit python.
Is there any way I can turn my iPhone or Android tablet into a GPS device and export the coordinate into a file. Then, I can run a code to read that file to make the drone to follow those GPS coordinates. 
Or Can I use iPhone to communicate directly and continuously to the python script to make to drone follow the iPhone( or adroid)?

I really really appreciate if someone can help me. It took me so long to do research, but I got nothing so far.

Thank you so much.

the code "follow_me" is below:
https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/tree/master/examples/follow_me

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar apps to log gps data from android phone.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger&hl=en

In fact, you can develop your own android app(fairly easy) which broadcasts coordinates, and do lots of stuff with the drone...